# Goggle Colab: Variable tpu_140268413570632//kernel/0 already exists

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I'm using google colab for the first time, and I'm testing the TPU. But when I run my keras model, I get the error `ValueError: Variable tpu_140268413570632//kernel/0 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`
For transphorming the keras model to tpu model, I use  this code
`model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(keras_model, strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])))`

Here is link to the code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18uzgCgg1LGGRowgzq997rZSwkL832jpB

Any idea why I get this error?

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem you observe?

Comment: Hum... Very strange, that working now. But since yesterday it raised an error. Here is a link to my code, no special things to declared: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18uzgCgg1LGGRowgzq997rZSwkL832jpB

Comment: And it begins again. Do you think that a bug?

Comment: Did you figure out how/what caused it to work/not work?

Comment: No, I did not. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: The link looks broken. Would you mind reposting it?

Answer (score 0):

The code link isn't active anymore or I don't have access to it.

One issue that I see is the way you configure a TPUStrategy. Here is a code sample to correctly initialize a TPUStrategy. 
Make sure you have selected TPU in the Colab runtime.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
```

For more info please have a look at the TPU [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu).

Comment: Your code is right, but probably isn't the solution. Since my original post, the initialization method has changed for yours, it is why my code seems wrong now. But I haven't had any errors for a long time now, may be google has solved the problem.